# Change Email with Phone number on Woocommerce Order Tracking Form or Simply track with only order number

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to change the Email field with the phone field to track order status on the WooCommerce order tracking form page. if not possible then I want to simply disable the Email field so my client can track their order status by entering just order number.

inside order/form-tracking.php I tried replacing "order_email" with "order_phone" and even tried replacing it with "billing_phone" but did not track any shipment.
The last try I made and tried to remove following entire Email section code,

```
<p class="form-row form-row-last"><label for="order_email"><?php esc_html_e( 'Billing email', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label> <input class="input-text" type="text" name="order_email" id="order_email" value="<?php echo isset( $_REQUEST['order_email'] ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_REQUEST['order_email'] ) ) : ''; ?>" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Email you used during checkout.', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" /></p><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
```

But it didn't work and still says Email required.
Any help will be highly appreciated, please...

Answer (score 2):

It's been late though but here is your answer, you have to change in `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/shortcodes/class-wc-shortcode-order-tracking.php` as well.

```
if ( isset( $_REQUEST['orderid'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $nonce_value, 'woocommerce-order_tracking' ) ) { // WPCS: input var ok.

            $order_id    = empty( $_REQUEST['orderid'] ) ? 0 : ltrim( wc_clean( wp_unslash( $_REQUEST['orderid'] ) ), '#' ); // WPCS: input var ok.
            $order_phone = empty( $_REQUEST['order_phone'] ) ? '' : ( wc_sanitize_phone_number( $_REQUEST['order_phone'] ) ); // WPCS: input var ok.

            if ( ! $order_id ) {
                wc_print_notice( __( 'Please enter a valid order ID', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
            } elseif ( ! $order_phone ) {
                wc_print_notice( __( 'Please enter a valid phone number', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
            } else {
                $order = wc_get_order( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_shortcode_order_tracking_order_id', $order_id ) );

                if ( $order && $order->get_id() && wc_sanitize_phone_number( $order->get_billing_phone() ) ===  $order_phone ) {
                    do_action( 'woocommerce_track_order', $order->get_id() );
                    wc_get_template(
                        'order/tracking.php',
                        array(
                            'order' => $order,
                        )
                    );
                    return;
                } else {
                    wc_print_notice( __( 'Sorry, the order could not be found. Please contact us if you are having difficulty finding your order details.', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
                }
            }
        }

        wc_get_template( 'order/form-tracking.php' );
    }
```

and in `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/order/form-tracking.php`

```
<p class="form-row form-row-last"><label for="order_phone"><?php esc_html_e( 'Billing phone number', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label> <input class="input-text" type="text" name="order_phone" id="order_phone" value="<?php echo isset( $_REQUEST['order_phone'] ) ? esc_attr( wc_sanitize_phone_number( $_REQUEST['order_phone'] ) ) : ''; ?>" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Phone number you used during checkout.', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" /></p><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
```